# Python Tensorflow error for the imageai library image Prediction ```ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'```

Tags: python, tensorflow, imageai

https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI for the package

Built with simplicity in mind, ImageAI supports a list of state-of-the-art Machine Learning algorithms for image prediction, custom image prediction, object detection, video detection, video object tracking and image predictions trainings. ImageAI currently supports image prediction and training using 4 different Machine Learning algorithms trained on the ImageNet-1000 dataset. ImageAI also supports object detection, video detection and object tracking using RetinaNet, YOLOv3 and TinyYOLOv3 trained on COCO dataset. Finally, ImageAI allows you to train custom models for performing detection and recognition of new objects.

Eventually, ImageAI will provide support for a wider and more specialized aspects of Computer Vision including and not limited to image recognition in special environments and special fields.

I am trying to build an imageai project where it gives predictions to an image. but my code gives errors which I don't understand

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
from tensorflow import *
import os

exe = os.getcwd()

prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsSqueezeNet()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(exe, "squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5"))
prediction.loadModel()


predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(exe, "Cake.jpg"), result_count=10)

for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction, " : ", eachProbability)
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jezon Fernando/Desktop/Tutorials/PROGRAMING/PYTHON 3/AI/photo_recorgnizer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\imageai\Prediction\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: From your error: "See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help."

Comment: You need to have a 64 bit Python and ensure to have latest [MSVC redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) and the Python binary is installed from official sources, not from Windows marketplace.Thanks!